# How to get on the internet without going through domain

Tags: internet, domain

My personal laptop is not on my company's domain, but I can take it to work and get on the internet just fine and go wherever I want on the internet.

My work laptop is on the company domain and is subject to very restrictive filters and I can't get on many sites that I often want to go to just to do my job (I can't, for example, login to stackoverflow from my work computer).

I talked to our network admin and he removed most of the filters so I can pretty much get to wherever I need to go, but here's my question:

Is there a way I can make my work laptop access the internet as though it wasn't on the domain (without actually removing it from the domain, obviously)?  If I am not subject to the filters on my personal laptop which is not on the domain, then it seems like I ought to be able to trick it somehow into letting me do that with my work laptop as well.

Comment: (unsolicited advice) In general, it is a bad idea to attempt to skirt company security policies.  They are there to protect the company which in turn protects your job. skirting them is often grounds for dismissal.

Comment: @uSlackr I have a global admin account I can change the policies myself with if I knew enough about doing that.  I'm not a $10/hr data entry employee that needs to be kept from wasting time on the internet.  I assure you it's okay for me to remove obstacles that are restricting my productivity.

Comment: I didn't say anything about your ability to not stay focused on the job.